# Why is this Factory function not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built what I thought was a functioning authentication factory but when I try to call Login.auth() an error throws saying that it is not a function. I have a different factory/controller pair that works perfectly fine and follows the same pattern as this example. 
Here is my code:
 
**Login Factory:**

```
app.factory('Login', ['$firebaseAuth', function($firebaseAuth) {
var authref = $firebaseAuth(ref);
var authData = {};
return {
    auth: function() {
        if (!authData) {
            authref.$authWithOAuthPopup("google", {
                scope: "email"
            }).then(function(data) {
                //check if account is made, if not create a new account and pass on.
                checkIfUserExists(data);
                authdata = {
                    user: {
                        name: data.google.displayName,
                        pic: data.google.profileImageURL
                    },
                    token: data.token,
                    provider: data.provider,
                    uid: data.uid
                };
                return authData;
            });
        }
        else {
            return authData;
        }
    },
    unAuth: function() {
        ref.unauth();
        authData = null;
        return authData;
    }
}
// Tests to see if /users/<userId> has any data. 
function checkIfUserExists(data) {
    usersRef.child(data.uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
        userExistsCallback(data, exists); //send the data and the boolean to userExistsCallback.
    });
}

function userExistsCallback(data, exists) {
    if (exists) {
        alert('user ' + data.google.id + ' exists!');
    } else {
        ref.child('users').child(data.uid).set({ //create a new user at the user/<$uid>/ path
            google_id: data.google.id,
            provider: data.provider,
            name: data.google.displayName,
            email: data.google.email,
            pic: data.google.profileImageURL
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

**Friends Ctrl**

```
app.controller('FriendsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ListFriends', 'Login', function($scope, ListFriends, Login) {
$scope.friends = {
    findNew: {
        query: '',
        search: null,
        found: {},
        add: null
    },
    findCurrent: null
};
$scope.authData = {};
Login.auth().then(function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.authData.uid = data.uid;
}, function errorCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
$scope.friends.findCurrent = function() {
    ListFriends.fetch($scope.authData.uid).then(function successCallback(data) {
        /* Format for the data comes packaged like this:
    {
    <uid>: {
        email: <email>,
        google_ID: <googleID>,
        name: <name>,
        pic: <picURL>,
        uid: <uid>
        }
    } 

    Store the dynamic uids in an array that can be ennumerated through.
    We are going to store this in a $scope.friends object        
    */
        var ojectIndicies = Object.keys(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < objectIndicies.length; i++) {
            var id = data[objectIndicies[i]].uid;
            var name = data[objectIndicies[i]].name;
            var email = data[objectIndicies[i]].email;
            var pic = data[objectIndicies[i]].pic;
            $scope.friends = {
                id: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    pic,
                    pic
                }
            };
            console.dir("The Friends object now looks like this:" + $scope.friends)
        }
    }, function errorCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
}]);
```

Any help at all would be great

**Edit #1:**
I have placed the entirety of the functionality in a plnkr
[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ASrB6kEIyjX5jBLgPzB?p=preview). So far no recommendations have made an impact, I am wondering if this might even be an HTML problem so that's why I created the plnkr.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how/why a little better?

Comment: You have `Login.puth()`. That should be `Login.auth()`.

Comment: @Lex that doesn't affect it, I had tried to change the name to see if auth was a reserved word but it wasn't, that's just my forgetting to switch it back. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Everything looks correct. Are you getting any other errors in the console before the error about Login.auth() not being a function? If you are using the minified version of angular.js try using the non-minified version to see if it gives you any more descriptive error messages.

Comment: I could be totally off, but change `'FriendsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ListFriends', 'Login', function($scope, ListFriends, Login)` to `'FriendsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ListFriends', 'Login', function($scope, Login, ListFriends)` and see if it works. The order of Login / ListFriends is altered in the callback

Comment: @Lex No other errors, I'll try adding the non-minified version.

Comment: @httpNick That didn't change anything, could you maybe show an example of the scope issue you were talking about earlier?

Comment: I just realized that you are returning an object from `Login.auth()`, but in your controller you are treating it as if it's returning a promise. That may be why it's giving you an error.

Comment: Tried doing `var someVar = Login.login();` and got the same error.

Comment: I think i know whats up. There must be another factory 'Login' which is replacing your code. Check your project for Duplicate factories

Comment: @SaneeshB there are two factories and two controllers. One is `ListFriends` the other is `Login`. They belong to the `FriendsCtrl` and `LoginCtrl` respectively. I am using the login factory in the ListFriends factory to share auth data necessary to make CRUD calls

Comment: @MattSanford I mean there might be a totally different Angular module not part of this code "may be in firebase" that has a Login Factory which is overriding your code, im guessing.